# Is there a Haskell readMaybe function for Text?

Tags: haskell, text

Question says it all: Is there a [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Text-Read.html#g:3) for [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) ? I cannot seem to find a package to implement it.

Comment: Is performance a concern, or would  `pack <$> readMaybe` suffice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you looking for a function `Read a => Text -> Maybe a`? Use `readMaybe . unpack`. Unfortunately there's no way to make it more efficient since the `Read` typeclass is restricted to `String`. If you need it to be from `Text`s without any intermediate step, you'd have to implement an `attoparsec` or `parsec` parser.